# CPLEX and Python 3.7

Tags: python, cplex

I'm trying to use cplex with python version 3.7.3. CPLEX has a setup.py for version 3.7, but when I try to use it I still get the error "CPLEX 12.9.0.0 is not compatible with this version of Python". Is there a workaround for this or do I need to downgrade to Python 3.6?

Comment: What operating system are you on? Do you have multiple versions of Python on your system? You have to run setup.py with the correct version of Python. Show us what you get if you just run python and drop into the interactive prompt (i.e., it will show us the version information).

Comment: OS = windows. I have 3.7.3 and 3.6.8. I ran setup using 3.7. Now I running setup using 3.6. "C:\Program Files\IBM\ILOG\CPLEX_Studio_Community129\cplex\python\2.7\x64_win64\cplex\_internal\_pycplex_platform.py". I get this error. I assume it's trying to use 2.7,but I don't know how to specify 3.6 because I already ran setup for 3.6 @rkersh

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's assume the Python 3.7 executable is located at `C:\Python37\python.exe` and CPLEX 12.9 is installed at `C:\Program Files\IBM\ILOG\CPLEX_Studio_Community129`. Then, to install the CPLEX Python API, you would do something like the following:

```
cd "C:\Program Files\IBM\ILOG\CPLEX_Studio_Community129\cplex\python\3.7\x64_win64\"
C:\Python37\python.exe setup.py install
```

The installation instructions for the CPLEX Python API can be found [here](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSA5P_12.9.0/ilog.odms.cplex.help/CPLEX/GettingStarted/topics/set_up/Python_setup.html).

Comment: Right, I did all these things. I changed the pythonpath to C:\Program Files\IBM\ILOG\CPLEX_Studio_Community129\cplex\python\3.7\x64_win64. But it's still trying to use the 2.7 path

Comment: All I had to do was change the Path. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

Yes,

To my knowledge for the optimization solvers
CPLEX and DOCPLEX you need to downgrade to Python 3.6 currently.

Answer (score 0):

I myself had to downgrade to Python 3.6 because I had the same problem but that was because Python 3.7 is 32-bit and the CPLEX API requires 64-bit (I can't tell you why, but that's just what I learned). Once you install Python 3.6 64-bit then you can download the CPLEX and DOPLEX packages so easily you'll hate that you didn't do it in the first place.

Comment: You don't have to downgrade. You can install the 64bit version of Python 3.7 instead.