# Python API setup problem with CPLEX 20.1.0

Tags: python, api, mathematical-optimization, cplex

An error was shown when I try to set up the Python API for CPLEX. The verison of CPLEX is 20.1.0 and the python version in its installation package is 3.7 and 3.8. I have installed Python 3.7.0 and operate following the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56634674/cplex-and-python-3-7) and the [official instruction](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/icos/20.1.0?topic=cplex-setting-up-python-api).
When it was about to completed, I received an error `Exception: this 'cplex' package (version 20.1.0.0) is not compatible with this version of Python: expected 3.8 but got 3.9`
My Python version is like this:

```js
C:\>python
Python 3.7.0 (v3.7.0:1bf9cc5093, Jun 27 2018, 04:59:51) [MSC v.1914 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
```

But I haven't installed Python 3.9 and I've checked I don't have this version on my computer. Here is the error information:

```js
C:\Program Files\IBM\ILOG\CPLEX_Studio201\cplex\python\3.8\x64_win64>py setup.py install
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\IBM\ILOG\CPLEX_Studio201\cplex\python\3.8\x64_win64\setup.py", line 91, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Program Files\IBM\ILOG\CPLEX_Studio201\cplex\python\3.8\x64_win64\setup.py", line 72, in main
    check_version()
  File "C:\Program Files\IBM\ILOG\CPLEX_Studio201\cplex\python\3.8\x64_win64\setup.py", line 45, in check_version
    raise Exception(
Exception: this 'cplex' package (version 20.1.0.0) is not compatible with this version of Python: expected 3.8 but got 3.9
```

Please let me know your suggestions~ Thank you so much! ;-)

Comment: If you got python 3.7 and use the installer of 3.8 it's wrong anyway. So fix that first. Then, if still not working out, double-check everything. What happens when calling `python` in console? How to env-vars look like (PATH, PYTHONPATH)?

Comment: Hello sascha, thanks for your comments. I have checked my python versions and my path in the environment variables are like this: C:\Program Files\IBM\ILOG\CPLEX_Studio201\cplex\python\3.7\x64_win64. But the problems are still the same, so do you have any further suggestions. Thanks a lot~